# How to add lazy relation to other Anorm backed class

Tags: scala, playframework, anorm

Question: **How do I add a lazy relation from one Anorm backed class to another?**

I would like to have a lazy relation from an Anorm backed class to another class/table.
So when I have a Foo, and I do a getBar, the SQL query will be fired right then. I'm sure it is a newbie question, but there is very little documentation about Anorm around, and yet it seems to be the persistence layer of choice for Play on Scala.

Comment: i have this question as well, and it's not too vague, did you ever find more information?

Comment: My conclusion is that it is not supported. In general Anorm is very poorly documented. I switched to Squeryl which has many advantages over Anorm, including type safety.

Comment: i figured out how to do it: https://github.com/dustingetz/orm-deep-dive/blob/master/app/models/Environment.scala.scala